# docker-compose up not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04

Below command not working in my system.

```
docker-compose up
```

I got this error, Please help me to get out of this.

In file './docker-compose.yml' service 'version' doesn't have any configuration options. All top level keys in your docker-compose.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options.

Answer (score 2):

That error would be reported if you were using a the Compose v2 format, with a version of Compose that doesn't support it.

You should download an official Compose build using these instructions https://docker.github.io/compose/install/

The package that is provided by the ubuntu repo may be pretty old.